# Where is X509's name field in openssl 1.1.0?

Tags: c, openssl

I am migrating an application from openssl 1.0.2 to 1.1.0. The problem is the name field in X509 struct is missing, so I don't know how to update the code like `cert->name` now.

openssl 1.0.2

```
struct x509_st {
    X509_CINF *cert_info;
    X509_ALGOR *sig_alg;
    ASN1_BIT_STRING *signature;
    int valid;
    int references;
    char *name;
    CRYPTO_EX_DATA ex_data;
    /* These contain copies of various extension values */
    long ex_pathlen;
    long ex_pcpathlen;
    unsigned long ex_flags;
    unsigned long ex_kusage;
    unsigned long ex_xkusage;
    unsigned long ex_nscert;
    ASN1_OCTET_STRING *skid;
    AUTHORITY_KEYID *akid;
    X509_POLICY_CACHE *policy_cache;
    STACK_OF(DIST_POINT) *crldp;
    STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME) *altname;
    NAME_CONSTRAINTS *nc;
# ifndef OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
    STACK_OF(IPAddressFamily) *rfc3779_addr;
    struct ASIdentifiers_st *rfc3779_asid;
# endif
# ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SHA
    unsigned char sha1_hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
# endif
    X509_CERT_AUX *aux;
} /* X509 */ ;
```

openssl 1.1.0

```
struct x509_st {
    X509_CINF cert_info;
    X509_ALGOR sig_alg;
    ASN1_BIT_STRING signature;
    int references;
    CRYPTO_EX_DATA ex_data;
    /* These contain copies of various extension values */
    long ex_pathlen;
    long ex_pcpathlen;
    uint32_t ex_flags;
    uint32_t ex_kusage;
    uint32_t ex_xkusage;
    uint32_t ex_nscert;
    ASN1_OCTET_STRING *skid;
    AUTHORITY_KEYID *akid;
    X509_POLICY_CACHE *policy_cache;
    STACK_OF(DIST_POINT) *crldp;
    STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME) *altname;
    NAME_CONSTRAINTS *nc;
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
    STACK_OF(IPAddressFamily) *rfc3779_addr;
    struct ASIdentifiers_st *rfc3779_asid;
# endif
    unsigned char sha1_hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    X509_CERT_AUX *aux;
    CRYPTO_RWLOCK *lock;
    volatile int ex_cached;
} /* X509 */ ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was unused. From the [mailing list](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2020-October/013039.html):

> although the name field was present in 1.0.2 it was not used for
> anything. So there was no point in keeping it once the structure was
> made non-public in 1.1.0.

Here's the commit if anyone is interested: [359aa38fbeec](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/359aa38fbeecd920a60c739c64cda06fe295684f)